# missing last column when inserting into DataTable using c#

Tags: c#

I have following string. I am trying to insert these details into dataTable but last columns in below string ("incident" column) not inserting into data table.The code is working based on first 4 column. I am getting these values from frontend using JavaScript and I have assigned to `string`.

String given below

```
[{"CompanayID":"k123","Role":"Admin","Country":"UK","Asset":"HD"},
 "CompanayID":"k234","Role":"User","Country":"US","Asset":"HD12","incident":"abc 1"}]
```

I have done following code but it doesn't take last column

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("UserDetails");
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            object[] objCustomers = (object[])serializer.DeserializeObject(customers);
            var columnNames = ((Dictionary<string, object>)objCustomers[0]).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(columnNames[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < objCustomers.Length; i++)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> keyValue = (Dictionary<string, object>)objCustomers[i];
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in keyValue)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < columnNames.Count(); k++)
                    {
                        if (item.Key == columnNames[k].ToString())
                        {
                            dr[columnNames[k]] = item.Value;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

Comment: Note that you create the columns based on the **first** json object in your json array. Take a close look at it...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I have removed +1. but that doesn't help. I have just given for testing purpose

Comment: Alright. But also consider the remainder of my first comment (i removed the bit with the IndexOutOfRangeException from my 1st comment, as it does not apply to the edited question anymore...)

Comment: The first object in the array does not have "incident". Is that a typo? I ask because what you are showing is not valid json and therefore would throw an error during de-serialization.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am getting this way from frontend . "Incident " column not available in first always.

Comment: @Jeremy invalid json aside, if you are using the values that don't include "incident" when creating data columns then how do you expect it to be there?

Comment: @Crowcoder. I have fixed that

Answer (score 0):

You are making the columns depending on the first object and it does not contain the last one 'incident'.
You Have more than a way to do it

**Adding the columns depending on the second object**

```
string customers = "[{\"CompanayID\":\"k123\",\"Role\":\"Admin\",\"Country\":\"UK\",\"Asset\":\"HD\"}, {\"CompanayID\":\"k234\",\"Role\":\"User\",\"Country\":\"US\",\"Asset\":\"HD12\",\"incident\":\"abc 1\"}]";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("UserDetails");
            var rows =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(customers);
            foreach (var c in rows[1])
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(c.Key);
            }
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (var innerColumn in row)
                {
                    dr[innerColumn.Key] = innerColumn.Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            
        }
```

**Add missing column to the first object as "" or null**

```
string customers = "[{\"CompanayID\":\"k123\",\"Role\":\"Admin\",\"Country\":\"UK\",\"Asset\":\"HD\",\"incident\":\"\"}, {\"CompanayID\":\"k234\",\"Role\":\"User\",\"Country\":\"US\",\"Asset\":\"HD12\",\"incident\":\"abc 1\"}]";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("UserDetails");
            var rows =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(customers);
            foreach (var c in rows[0])
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(c.Key);
            }
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (var innerColumn in row)
                {
                    dr[innerColumn.Key] = innerColumn.Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

**Update (Dynamic Way)**

```
string customers = "[{\"CompanayID\":\"k123\",\"Role\":\"Admin\",\"Country\":\"UK\",\"Asset\":\"HD\",\"incident\":\"\"}, {\"CompanayID\":\"k234\",\"Role\":\"User\",\"Country\":\"US\",\"Asset\":\"HD12\",\"incident\":\"abc 1\"}]";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("UserDetails");
            var rows =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(customers);
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (var innerColumn in row)
                {
                    if (!dt.Columns.Contains(innerColumn.Key))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(innerColumn.Key);
                    }
                    dr[innerColumn.Key] = innerColumn.Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

check https://dotnetfiddle.net/RsOu87